# Script manager stop working

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

i have a asp.net web project by c#. in master page, a simple function X, load some text from DB to show in all sub pages. 
now, when I disable this function, all scripts in sub pages are working, but when enable this function they stop!

```
protected void X()
{
    var db = new dbDataContext();//Use Linq
    var allText = db.tblX;

    HtmlGenericControl dangerDiv;
    HtmlGenericControl warningP;

    int i = 0;
    foreach (var record in allText)
    {
        dangerDiv = html2asp.createHTMLControl("dDIV", i);
//html2asp is my class that create a html tag
            warningP = html2asp.createHTMLControl("P", i);
            warningP.InnerText = record.subject + " : " + record.text;
            dangerDiv.Controls.Add(warningP);
            Warnings.Controls.Add(dangerDiv);
        }
    }
```

and in sub pages use scrip manager and update panel that way:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManagerCustomer" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPanelCustomer" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DataList ID="dataCustomers" runat="server" OnItemCommand="dataCustomers_ItemCommand" RepeatLayout="Table" class="table-striped " EnableViewState="true" Width="100%">
```

please help me to solve this problem. thank you

Comment: Hi, you should consider adding a [mcve], help us help you ;-)

Comment: @bradbury9 Hi, I changed my question and add my codes.

Comment: Is the Warning cointainer inside the UpdatePanel? Could you check the html generated? most probably the data inserted is breaking the html or the ajax response. In browser debugger you should be able tho check for javascript errors in the console or jailed ajax responses in the network responses.

Comment: @bradbury9 no, warning container outside it and before of  contentPlaceHolder...